# python Mysql SELECT data not refreshed

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi

*Non-commercial, non-professional user, seeking advice for hobbyist project.*

I'm trying to pull data from one Pi, and scroll it on a second Pi.

However, terminal is showing repeats of the data initially loaded, not fresh data that I can see in the database.
(For info...The database is updated automatically every ten minutes. For tests like this, I am running a manual update script to force new readings into the database.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import signal
import time
import scrollphathd
from scrollphathd.fonts import font5x7
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
con = mysql.connector.connect(host='192.168.###############')

str_len = 0
scroll_x = 0
timer = 2 # number of mins for display loop

### Create cursorS for each database element:
### Keep in buffer with =True
while True:
    curT = con.cursor(buffered=True)
    curY = con.cursor(buffered=True)
    curL = con.cursor(buffered=True)

### Use each cursor to read required data from database:
    curT.execute('SELECT Temp FROM readings ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 1')
    curY.execute('SELECT Yaxis FROM readings ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 1')
    curL.execute('SELECT Lux FROM readings ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 1') 

### Get rid of trailing comma from each SELECT result: 
    resultT = [row[0] for row in curT.fetchall()]
    resultY = [row[0] for row in curY.fetchall()]
    resultL = [row[0] for row in curL.fetchall()]



### Not essential, but let's show the 
### result of each SELECT query in the terminal:
    print resultT
    print resultY
    print resultL

    # set loop time in seconds
    start = time.time()
    end = start + ( timer + 60 )


### Set strings for display on Scroll PhatHD from SELECT results: 
    while time.time() < end:
            temperature = resultT[0]
            yaxis = resultY[0]
            lux = resultL[0]


### Dim down Scroll Phat HD, and clear its buffer:            
            scrollphathd.set_brightness(0.1)
            scrollphathd.clear()


### Uncomment/comment the below line to rotate Scroll PhatHD by 180/upside down
            scrollphathd.rotate(degrees=180)


### Uncomment line below to test all data on Scroll PhatHD in one go.
### str_len = scrollphathd.write_string(" :-) %.1fC Y%i L%i "%(temperature, yaxis, lux), brightness=0.5)


### Check light levels and door angle (Yaxis) and report appripriately. Always show the temperature:
            if lux <= 100 and yaxis >=3500 :
                str_len = scrollphathd.write_string("Garage: light off & door closed.  %.1fC Y%i "%(temperature, yaxis), x=0, y=0, font=font5x7)
            elif lux <= 100 and yaxis <500:
                str_len = scrollphathd.write_string("Garage: Light off & door open.  %.1fC "%(temperature), x=0, y=0, font=font5x7)        
            elif lux > 100 and yaxis <500:
                str_len = scrollphathd.write_string("Garage: Light on & door open.  %.1fC "%(temperature), x=0, y=0, font=font5x7)
            elif lux > 100 and yaxis >=3500:
                str_len = scrollphathd.write_string("Garage: Light on & door closed.  %.1fC "%(temperature), x=0, y=0, font=font5x7)
            elif yaxis >500 and yaxis <3499:
                str_len = scrollphathd.write_string("Garage door ajar %.1fC  "%(temperature), x=0, y=0, font=font5x7)


            scrollphathd.scroll_to(scroll_x, 0)
            scrollphathd.show()
            time.sleep(0.01)
            scroll_x += 1
            if scroll_x >= str_len:
                scroll_x = 0
```

What do I need to change to make the display show fresh data from the database, and not repeated show old stale data?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I do wonder if it's in the cursor buffer, and if that needs flushing somehow between each SELECT loop?

Comment: (Probably) unreleated, but your `end` variable should be `end = start + ( timer * 60 )`, not `end = start + ( timer + 60 )`, if `timer`'s units are in minutes.

Comment: You're right. I posted an older copy of my code that hadn't had that typo changed.

Comment: Is the sender using transactions, and committing after all the data is updated?

Comment: I don't know, how do I check and confirm?

Comment: Why are you using loops when your queries all have `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: Why are you using 3 separate queries instead of `SELECT Temp, Yaxis, Lux FROM readings ORDER BY Added DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: If you don't use `start_transaction` in the writing script then you're not using transactions.

Comment: LIMIT 1 is so that the data is always the most recent

Comment: Three separate SELECT queries as I was tying myself in knots trying keep the three data elements separate. I'm a beginner...

Comment: Data is added by ```cur.execute("INSERT INTO readings (Temp,Yaxis,Lux) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);", (TempVal, YaxisVal, LuxVal),)```
Data is commited ```mydb.commit()```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem with MySQL from different notebooks running Python. I was seeing obvious cases where my queries from one notebook was not seeing data being posted by the other ones.

This is a very simple solution, but I find it works well.

Just setup a fresh connection, then process the SQL, and at the end close the connection. Code in Python looks like:

```
import mysql.connector

def do_SQL_Stuff(rds_Dict):

   #Get RDS connection
   cnx_GDAX = mysql.connector.connect(
      host = rds_Dict['host'],
      user = rds_Dict['user'], 
      password = rds_Dict['password'],
      database = rds_Dict['database'])

   #Do SQL stuff

   #Close RDS connection
   cnx_GDAX.close()

   return r_Stuff
```

This works well for my coding and totally removed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

InnoDB problem with [REPEATABLE READ](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html#isolevel_repeatable-read), but a very simple solution I've come up is just by putting `con.commit()` in the end of your loop (before performing next SELECT). The commit method will clear the previous snapshot so the query will return the current real record. Cheers :)

Comment: Great tip! Also works with SQL Server using pyodbc